# JavaScript click button. Chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, browser

Hi guys I am going crazy after 3 days I can't figure out how I can click a button with a chrome extension.

I tried multiple discords none helped me YouTube chatgpt and allot of Google forums I just can't figure it out...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try this code?

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
  // Assuming the button has an ID of "myButton"
  let button = document.getElementById("myButton");

  if (button) {
    button.click();
  }
});
```